# What size gravel works best for a driveway?

Tags: driveway, stone, gravel

What is the best type of gravel for a driveway. Is it the larger sized so it does not get stuck in tires, if so what is that called.

Comment: Are you looking to make a stone driveway, or are you looking for base material for a non-stone driveway?

Comment: After clearing for my driveway we put down "3 inch minus". This is important for providing a stable base on our loose, clay-rich soil. After driving on it for a while, it packed down well. I was told we could put down some "3/4 inch minus" for a nicer finish, but haven't done that yet. Some hardware cloth might be a good idea, too.

Answer (score 2):

Driveway gravel is usually sized by the stone that is mixed with the sand.  Example: 3/8", 3/4" etc. A good driveway packing gravel is 3/4".  Another good choice is 3/8" stone dust. This material packs down very hard and smooth.

So when you call to order your material, ask for 3/4" packing gravel or 3/8" stone dust.