# Dirt Driveway Repairs

Tags: driveway, landscaping, gravel, grading

I have a long dirt driveway that is riddled with potholes.  I can’t afford to have the repair done for me or even to rent a bobcat. My thought is to have a load of driveway mix/stonecrete delivered and then move it by wheel barrow to the spots that need to be filled.  I’m not looking forward to this at all lol.  My question is how can I prevent the pile of gravel from settling so it stays workable for a while, possibly up to a week?

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/43874/stabilizing-a-gravel-driveway-with-massive-holes-and-steep-inclination/43880#43880 may provide some insight on low-cost repairs. Gravel should not be terribly hard to dig from a loose pile in even several weeks of sitting, from experience. If it does stiffen up, a pick or digging bar will loosen it. Put the pile high so you are moving downhill with the wheelbarrow, not uphill.

Comment: Choosing the correct "gravel" is important.   See this question. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/27464/what-size-gravel-works-best-for-a-driveway    **and this**  https://www.braenstone.com/crushed-stone-gravel-driveway/

Comment: I’m planning on getting some 23a crushed gravel

Answer (score 2):

A pile of gravel will be easy to move (read: Scoop into something). If you have any larger rocks then it gets hard to shovel. I would just request they send a truck with a dump bed that you can adjust the end gate. Then if you have free range (no trees or power lines) they can slowly drive forward and do a thin spread for you. Much easier to move where you need it this way and no wheelbarrow involved.

Comment: This is exactly what I did years ago. The driver did a pretty good job of spreading it on the driveways. Minimal shoveling was all that was needed.